# How can I count only comments that have added upvotes and not all comments

Tags: wordpress

welcome all,
Below is a code by which the percentage of ratings in this article is calculated from the comments.
What I want is to count only the number of comments that have added upvotes, and exclude other comments from the number of people who have already rated them.

```
global $post;    
    $stars   = '';
    $comments = get_comments( array( 'post_id'=>get_the_ID() ) );
    
    if( $comments ) {

        $average = ci_comment_rating_get_average_ratings( $post->ID );
        $total = count( $comments );

    } else {

        $average = 0;
        $total = 0;
    }
```

**Use these values:**

$average = For the appearance of the evaluation rate (3.5 / 5).

$total = Counts the number of comments already rated.

I used this to build a system of comments, reviews, and ratings:
https://www.cssigniter.com/add-rating-wordpress-comment-system/